# After PostBuild event Visual Studio/MS Build

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, csproj

I'm using the external lib `UnmanagedExports` in my C# console project (Visual Studio 2017). The csproj file of my project contains inter alia the following lines:

```
<DllExportLibToolPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x64</DllExportLibToolPath>
<NoDllExportsForAnyCpu>false</NoDllExportsForAnyCpu>
```

With help of these lines and the external lib my build process firstly generates two folders, x86 and x64. After that the Post Build event of the project copies the folders to another location.

**The problem:**

After changing/updating the lib, the build process order has changed. Now, the Post build event (copy) is executed and then the two folders are created. Of course, that does not work.

Is there a way to copy the folders after the build of the project is completed? The post build event is unfortunately running too soon.

Comment: See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-build-order?view=vs-2019), you can easily create a custom target with `AfterTargets="build"`, then running a [Exec task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task?view=vs-2019#example) in it. Copy the command from post-build-event to the command of Exec task. If it not works, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Works great. Thank you. Can you turn your comment  into an answer?

Comment: Yes , of course:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The post build event is unfortunately running too soon.

We can use [AfterTargets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-build-order?view=vs-2019#beforetargets-and-aftertargets) to control the build order.

Normally something like this would execute after the build is completed:

```
  <Target Name="CustomTarget" AfterTargets="build">
    <Exec Command="xxx"/>
    <!--copy the content from post-build event here-->
  </Target>
```

This target will execute even after post-build target.

And in some situations if it not work well, we can check the target we want to run after, then using something like `AfterTargets="TargetWhoCreateFolders"` to set the build order.